# Retrieve AbstractMavenProject Builders list in groovy

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, groovy

I would like to retrieve all the hudson.tasks.Builder of a hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProject projects.

From this script, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+jobs+group+by+the+build+steps+they+use, I can get all the builders of hudson.model.Project projects.

But hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProject does not have any property containing all the hudson.tasks.Builder builders.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: builders for class: hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet
```

Any idea how to get this information ?